# Can't place form in the center of the screen vertically and horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place this form horizontally and vertically in the center. Used the right classes of Bootstrap 4 to make it happen but it still on the top close to nav bar.

Here is the code:

**form screen**

```
  <section id="cover">
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="User email" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**app screen**

I am using angular so later each component screen goes through app component so that is why I am placing app component code as well:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<app-header> </app-header>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</div>
```

here is also css:

```
.container-fluid{
    padding:0;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So how can I move that form in the center of the screen from the top?

Comment: `#cover` has any height?

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Comment: I think that's the problem. If the container of an element has no height, it will have the height that the elements located inside it will give it, so they would be fited and could not be justified. html, body and the container(#cover) should have a height of 100%. Once they occupy the full height of the application and the container has a class to center the elements, the internal elements could be centered.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put your form in an element with a 100% height that justifies your content like so:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <section id="cover" class="col-12">
     <div class="container-fluid fill">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
       <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="User email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </section>
  </div>  
 </div>
```

And in your css

```
body,html{
height:100%;
}
```

Here's a [demo of your form](https://www.codeply.com/go/PfbEM63s3m)